# ASP.Net : How to update the database?

Tags: asp.net, database

I am using visual basic as the coding language.

```
    conSQL.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update Phd_Student set student_name = '" + studentnameTextBox.Text + "' where student_id = '" + studentidno.Text + "'", conSQL)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    conSQL.Close()
```

This does not change the value of the record. I created a breakpoint at line 2 and found that the value of studentnameTextBox.Text in the query is the old value even though I changed the text of the textbox in the form.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You'll need to post more code. This is a problem with your Windows Forms code, not your database code.

Comment: Dont pull data directly from UI...use Parameters to avoid Sql injection...as a side note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code isn't anywhere close to being secure.  Validate any input information before you use it in a query and consider using stored procedures as well.

And we'll need more information about the page state when you're trying to do this.

Also, put this code in an exception block and in the Finally block put the SQL close command.  If anything blows up you're going to want to make sure that the connection is still closed and Finally takes care of that.